# Should you preface build() and create() FactoryGirl methods with classname?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I'm on a Rails project and noticed that most of the spec files have something similar to the following:

```
new_user = create(:user)
```

The spec works fine, but since I'm using Rubymine, I get a complaint saying too many arguments.  Turns out, there's another class referenced in the spec_helper.rb that also has a create() method with no arguments.  During execution, the FactoryGirl method is used, but when I mentioned changing the call to:

```
new_user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
```

I received complaints from another team member saying the existing version is shorthand and FactoryGirl is assumed.  Listing out FactoryGirl in my implementation is more keystrokes.

I still think I have a point, since listing out the FactoryGirl class does make it absolutely clear which method is being used (not to mention quieting Rubymine), but should we just leave the code as is?

Comment: If I were you, I would avoid adapting my coding style to fit my IDE. It should be the other way around.

Comment: @Adrian, I agree, that's an excellent point, but most often I find JetBrain suggestions good practices (back from my Resharper days), and I think this one might be warranted.

Comment: The thoughtbot team recommends the shorthand so I'd be hard pressed to switch because of your IDE too.

Comment: omitting the FActoryGirl is the new pattern. Also, I agree with @Adrian, you shouldn't be adapting your code to your IDE.

Comment: Alright, I was hoping to get a consensus and seems like I'll leave as is, without the preface, thanks for the input!

Answer (score 2):

RubyMine 7 doesn't seem to support FactoryGirl syntax properly.

Check [this thread](https://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5530782) in JetBrains Developer community and [the mentioned issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-5014) on RubyMine issue tracker (You can vote up the issue for attention). In the community thread, a JetBrains developer suggests *disabling the inspection for entire test file* :(

Comment: Thanks @baxang, I was beginning to wonder about that myself, hopefully they fix the issue, disabling inspection seems like a hack workaround for sure.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this annoying issue of underlining FactoryGirl(Bot) methods in Rubymine create a file `spec/void/rubymine_stubs.rb` with content:

```
# stubs for FactoryGirl's magic methods for Rubymine
def create(*_args) end
def create_list(*_args) end
def build(*_args) end
def build_stubbed(*_args) end
```